# Weird issue with regex match

Tags: python, regex

I'm testing some regex.  It looks like this part is getting cut off: `ing.*_{FD_YYYYMMDD}.*`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the URL to the regex tester you are using? Also please check whether this regex tester is using python regexs and not JavaScript regex (or similar)

Comment: Can you share your python code?

Comment: Why don't you put some actual code into the question, rather than images we can't test? Take a look at [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: See relevant docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is a string representation of a match object. It should only be used for debugging, and it is truncated.

To see the string captured by a group (green), call `re.search(pattern, string).group(1)`

Comment: Oh, I see.  Ok, I think I have a handle on this now.  Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.